# Is it possible to create an object of a class based on Enum value passed in constructor, in C#?

Tags: c#, constructor, properties, enums

I am creating a small project where a user can create tests that contain Multiple Choice Questions. These MCQs can have either one correct answer or more than one. I have defined the classes as follows:

```
public class MultipleChoiceQuestionSingle : Question
{
    public string[] Options { get; set; }
    public int CorrectOption { get; set; }
}

public class MultipleChoiceQuestionMultiple : Question
{
    public string[] Options { get; set; }
    public int[] CorrectOptions { get; set; }
}
```

What I am trying to do is to have a constructor for `MultipleChoiceQuestion` as

```
public MultipleChoiceQuestion(McqType mcqType)
{

}

public enum McqType
{ 
    SingleAnswer = 0,
    MultipleAnswers = 1
}
```

Will it be possible to create an instance of `MultipleChoiceQuestion` for Single answer or Multiple answer with the properties `string[] Options & string CorrectOption` or `string[] Options & string[] CorrectOptions` respectively, depending upon what Enum value is selected while initiating the object? I have been trying to play around for a while now and am pretty confused as to if any of the OOPS concepts can be used to achieve this. Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You have not defined class `MultipleChoiceQuestion`. Did you mean `Question`?

Comment: @MrAnderson I have defined 2 classes here. The class MultipleChoiceQuestion is the one I am trying to create that will instantiate with different properties depending upon the Enum McqType selected. The first part is what I have right now, and the second part is what I am trying to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that's called a [factory method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).  It's a very common design pattern.  I assume you don't need some example code since it's pretty trivial.  It seems like you were just looking to corroborate your approach.

Comment: Scoured my factory design pattern concepts and now I am good to go. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
public MultipleChoiceQuestion(McqType mcqType)
{
   Question q;
   switch (mcqType) {
      case SingleAnswer:
         q = new MultipleChoiceQuestionSingle();
         break;
      case MultipleAnswers:
         q = new MultipleChoiceQuestionMultiple();
         break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of derailing the thread, I need to point something out. All your questions have *n* correct answers. For some questions, *n* is 1, and for others, it's more than that. I don't think you need two classes and a SOLID-breaking case statement to model this fact.

Just use a single `Question` class, and have some of the questions only have one correct answer.

Also, rather than having an array of answers and then a separate array of the indices of the correct ones, have correctness be a property of the answer. You end up with something like this:

```
class Answer
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool Correct { get; set; }
}

class Question
{
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    var test = new List<Question>
    {
        new Question 
        { 
            QuestionText = "What colour is the sky?",
            Answers = new List<Answer>
            {
                new Answer { Text = "Blue", Correct = true },
                new Answer { Text = "Red", Correct = false },
                new Answer { Text = "Green", Correct = false }
            }
        },
        new Question
        {
            QuestionText = "Which animals can swim?",
            Answers = new List<Answer>
            {
                new Answer { Text = "Ducks", Correct = true },
                new Answer { Text = "Fish", Correct = true },
                new Answer { Text = "Horses", Correct = false }
            }
        }
    };

    // do stuff with the test
}
```

Comment: This seems like a viable solution. And scalable too, if I feel like adding other types of question. Thanks a lot for this solution. However, from a learning perspective, I am still looking forward to get a solution without changing the structure of the business objects.